# nacasha CIgniter-Datatables column styling

Tags: codeigniter-3

```
$t->datatable('employees_table') // table's id
->column('First Name', 'first_name')
->column('Last Name', 'last_name')
->column('Age', 'age')
->column('Salary', 'title');

$t->datatable('employees_table')
->style(array(
    'class' => 'table table-bordered table-striped',
))
$t->init();
```

All I want to give a width and background etc to Age Column

Comment: pls specify the name nacasha , provide link if passible

Comment: link of the library https://github.com/nacasha/CIgniter-Datatables